# Calling correct generic interface implementation based on base generic type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

This question centers on dependency injection and generic interfaces.

One of my business entities is an ID card. There can be multiple types of ID cards, all inheriting from `ICard`:

```
interface ICard
{
    string CardId { get; }
}

class CardA : ICard
{
    string CardId { get; set; }
    string SomethingCardASpecific { get; set; }
}

class CardB : ICard
{
    string CardId { get; set; }
    bool SomethingCardBSpecific { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `CardFactory` that takes a card ID and returns the correct card type (as `ICard`):

```
class CardFactory : ICardFactory // Trivial interface definition left out
{
    ICard FromCardId(string cardId)
    {
        if (MatchesPatternA(cardId))
        {
            return new CardA { CardId = cardId /* ... */ }
        }
        else
        {
            return new CardB { CardId = cardId /* ... */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I have another dependency that checks if the card is authorized to perform some action. The logic depends on the card type, hence the generic interface:

```
interface ICardAuthorization<TCard> where TCard : ICard
{
    bool IsOperationXPermitted(TCard card);

    bool IsOperationYPermitted(TCard card);
}
```

I have an API controller that depends on `ICardFactory` and `ICardAuthorization`. An action receives a `cardId`, creates a card, and checks whether it's authorized for action X. The controller is not concerned with the fact that authorization is handled differently for the two card types, so it should depend on operations on the "base" card type (interface), i.e., `ICardAuthorization<ICard>`.

**The actual question:**

Naturally, I need at least two different implementations of `ICardAuthorization`, namely

```
class CardAAuthorization : ICardAuthorization<CardA> { /* ... */ }
class CardBAuthorization : ICardAuthorization<CardB> { /* ... */ }
```

However, using the design described above, the API needs to depend on the interface typed to `ICard`:

```
class DelegatingCardAuthorization : ICardAuthorization<ICard> { /* ... */ }
```

This, in turn, depends on the two "real" workhorses, `ICardAuthorization<CardA>` and `ICardAuthorization<CardB>`, and calls the correct one based on the type of the `ICard` its methods receive.

And of course, in my app, `ICardAuthorization<TCard>` is just one of several interfaces that needs different implementations for different card types.

This seems to me a fairly robust way to structure things, but I don't like the fact that I need delegating implementations that check types and forward calls to other implementations. I can live with it, no problem, but **is there any way to make this more elegant by removing the need for the delegating implementation?** (I'm using SimpleInjector if that matters.)

Comment: Can you give some more detail what happens with a card after it has been created? Is it directly returned to the web api client? Or is it further passed on to a business layer of some sort?

Comment: It's not returned to the client, it's just used in the business layer to identify a user.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't just remove the need the delegating implementation entirely because the logic to select an action based on card type should reside somewhere.

What I propose, however, is to go along with factories.

Create `CardAuthorizationFactory` which will return appropriate `ICardAuthorization` implemetor based on the type of the `ICard` object, passed to it. Create any number of other factories for other card actions. Put all those as singletons into IoC.

Now, when some method needs to do something with a card using authorization, it should query `AuthorizationFactory` for the `CardAuthorization` object appropriate for the card object it currently has. Factory should be injected into it by IoC. Will it suite your needs?

Comment: Thanks! I fail to see what benefits this has over the delegator. The number of classes are the same, and this would require one more interface (for the factory). But thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: @cmeeren At least one of the benefits I see is that a factory is much more known pattern to go with than custom delegation classes.